# Updates Installed without asking password

Tags: software-installation, password, update-manager

Software Updater installed updates on my computer without asking any password. Is it normal or suspicious? It always asked for password in times before. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I haven't tweaked anything to bypass entering passwords. Here is the corresponding part of dpkg.log:

```
2014-10-14 19:23:56 startup archives unpack
2014-10-14 19:24:00 upgrade ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1 7:2.4.2~trusty1.1
2014-10-14 19:24:00 status half-configured ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1
2014-10-14 19:24:00 status unpacked ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1
2014-10-14 19:24:00 status half-installed ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1
2014-10-14 19:24:04 status half-installed ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1
2014-10-14 19:24:04 status unpacked ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1.1
2014-10-14 19:24:04 status unpacked ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1.1
2014-10-14 19:24:04 upgrade python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.1
2014-10-14 19:24:04 status half-configured python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1
2014-10-14 19:24:05 status unpacked python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1
2014-10-14 19:24:05 status half-installed python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1
2014-10-14 19:24:05 status half-installed python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1
2014-10-14 19:24:05 status unpacked python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.1
2014-10-14 19:24:05 status unpacked python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.1
2014-10-14 19:24:05 upgrade liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:05 status half-configured liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:05 status unpacked liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:05 status half-installed liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:06 status half-installed liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:06 status unpacked liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:06 status unpacked liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:06 upgrade liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:06 status half-configured liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:06 status unpacked liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:06 status half-installed liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:09 status half-installed liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:10 status unpacked liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:10 status unpacked liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:10 upgrade oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:10 status half-configured oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:10 status unpacked oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:10 status half-installed oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:10 status half-installed oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.1.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:10 status unpacked oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:10 status unpacked oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:11 startup packages configure
2014-10-14 19:24:11 configure ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1.1 <none>
2014-10-14 19:24:11 status unpacked ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1.1
2014-10-14 19:24:11 status half-configured ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1.1
2014-10-14 19:24:11 status installed ffmpeg:amd64 7:2.4.2~trusty1.1
2014-10-14 19:24:11 configure python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.1 <none>
2014-10-14 19:24:11 status unpacked python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.1
2014-10-14 19:24:11 status half-configured python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.1
2014-10-14 19:24:11 status installed python3-requests:all 2.2.1-1ubuntu0.1
2014-10-14 19:24:11 configure oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 <none>
2014-10-14 19:24:11 status unpacked oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:12 status half-configured oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:12 status installed oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:12 configure liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 <none>
2014-10-14 19:24:12 status unpacked liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:12 status half-configured liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:12 status installed liboxideqtcore0:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:12 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.3
2014-10-14 19:24:12 configure liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 <none>
2014-10-14 19:24:12 status unpacked liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:12 status half-configured liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:12 status installed liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 1.2.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
2014-10-14 19:24:12 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.3 <none>
2014-10-14 19:24:12 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.3
2014-10-14 19:24:13 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.3
```

Comment: My Thinkpad usually has a pop-up with updates when I log in and it doesn't ask for my password. Maybe because I just logged in it doesn't bother for the password? idk. Anyways, I would say this is normal behavior.

Comment: @dash-plus-java Thank you, in my case too it was just after I logged in, I wonder if somebody can give a more technical justification to the cause you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable unattended upgrades? You can allow it to install security upgrades automatically (I do), so that maybe it. Check the Software Sources settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but no I haven't enabled unattended upgrades.